# Repeat the popup using php

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have image directory, All images i showing up on the page but now i want to a popup when the user will click on the image, The code i am using is

```
        #overlay {
      display:none;    
       position:fixed;  
       left:0px;        
    top:0px;         
        width:100%;      
           height:100%;     
        background:#000; 
       opacity:0.5;     
        z-index:99999;   
  }

      #popup{
        display:none;
        position:fixed;
      left:50%;        
      top:50%;         
      width:300px;     
      height:150px;
     margin-top:-75px;
      margin-left:-150px;
      background:#FFFFFF;
         border:2px solid #000;
       z-index:100000;      
       }</style>

         <script>window.onload = function() {
         document.getElementById("picss").onclick = function(){
            var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
          var popup = document.getElementById("popup ");
         overlay.style.display = "block";
          popup.style.display = "block";
          };</script>  



       <?php $imgdir = 'images/pictures'.$idd.'/';
     $files = glob( $imgdir ."*.*");
    for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
        {
      $num = $files[$i];



 echo '<a href="'.$num.'"  id="picss"><img src="'.$num.'"           class="actor_images" width ="220" /></a>';

  }

    ?>
```

Php code is working fine but the how can i have the popup on each image on the click of the image, for now its going to image url. i implements the popup but did not work, How can i repeat the popup using php.
Please Help! 
Thanks

Comment: Play with the classes..You can not have multiple elements having same class..

Comment: This is what my question is , I want to to repeat the class in loop, like         #overlay2..

Comment: Where is element having id `overlay2` ?

Answer (score 0):

> Give class as `picss`(`class="picss"`) instead of `id`

Try this:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var elems = document.getElementByClassName("picss");
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].onclick = function() {
      var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
      var popup = document.getElementById("popup ");
      overlay.style.display = "block";
      popup.style.display = "block";
    };
  }
};
```

Comment: This is how am using php with your code but a blank page comes up even images are not showing up now.<?php $imgdir = 'images/pictures'.$idd.'/';
   $files = glob( $imgdir ."*.*");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
 $num = $files[$i];
?> 

<div id="overlay"></div><div id="popup">
<?php 
 echo '<a href="'.$num.'"  class="picss"><img src="'.$num.'" class="actor_images" width ="220" /></a>';
?> </div><?php } ?>